# Building postgres with specific openssl

Tags: postgresql, makefile, configure

How can I build Postgres from source while specifying a specific version of openssl to use during the build? I don't want to use a distro-specific installation of openssl, so anything like `apt-get install libssl-dev` is out.

It looks like the configure script included with the Postgres source (v9.3.5) has two options, `--with-includes` and `--with-libraries`, that look like they should allow me to add additional search locations for libraries when configuring, but I've been unable to get the configure script to find a specific version of openssl.

I'm relatively new to building from source using nonstandard or local libraries, so any additional input is appreciated.

Comment: Why would you want to do this in the first place?

Comment: Need to be able to install a full stack application on devices that cannot have compilers or network access, as well as on various different developer machines, all with specific versions of every tool in the stack.